# Manga where male main character got isekaied and turned into a witch girl

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, isekai

Looking for an isekai manga where the (male) main character died (I forgot how he died) and got isekaied as a dark-haired female witch that lives in the middle of the forest alone, and has a hobby of making adult toys.

Comment: By 'adult toys' do you mean [toys aimed at the adult market](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/categories/ultimate-collector-series) or do you mean sex toys?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is ***[I Don't Really Get It, but It Looks like I Was Reincarnated in Another World](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=158385)***.

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/this-is-screwed-up-but-i-was-reincarnated-as-a-girl-in-another-world):

> Ren is a young girl in a primitive world of magic and brutality. Sold as a slave and about to be delivered to an unscrupulous merchant, she suddenly awakens to vivid memories of a past life: a world called Earth, where Ren was both a grown man and a research scientist. Now, she must learn to survive, combining her knowledge of science from her past life with her talent in magic from this life.

The story begins with a dark-haired, young girl named Ren waking up in a forest, next to a carriage and some dead bodies. The carriage was transporting her from the orphanage she lived in to the orphanage's benefactor, when it was attacked by bandits, leaving her as the sole survivor.

Furthermore, she's also just regained memories of a past life in another world, where she was a 30-year-old, male research scientist, who was killed in a car accident. In the here-and-now, however, it's cold and raining, and Ren realises she needs to find shelter and warmth in order to avoid dying of hypothermia.

In her current body, Ren has various magical skills, but doesn't seem to know much about them yet. By combining what little she does know of magic with her knowledge of science from her past life, she's able to build a small shelter out of twigs, and use magic to keep it dry and to start a fire within it, to keep her warm.

While sleeping in her shelter, she has a dream about being taken advantage of, sexually, by the benefactor of her orphanage. Fearing that something like that could happen to her for real, she decides to remain in the forest, rather than heading to a more populated area.

A few days later, she's now concerned about dying from hunger and thirst, and discovers she can use magic to summon water from thin air, and to make a rice ball appear in her hands. She also manages to access a status screen, which reveals that she has a number of magical skills, including 'Creation', 'Storage', and 'Appraisal'.

None of these skills are at very high levels initially, but drawing on her knowledge of science, along with materials in her immediate surroundings, she gradually learns how to make better use of them, and levels up, to a point where she's able to conjure up a barbecue, and then a rather nice house for herself in the middle of the forest.

While living in this house, the male aspect of her psyche also finds much pleasure in experimenting with the act of masturbation in a female body, and eventually conjures up various sex toys to further those experiments... purely in the name of scientific research, of course.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A very amusing manga. A lot of fanservice and a lot of food porn because this is one of those manga where every chapter or two, we get a few lovingly detailed pages of them cooking a favorite dish.