# Manga with a female character who reincarnates and makes potions

Tags: story-identification, manga

This is a manga about a girl who is sent to another world. She has a house pretty much in the middle of nowhere and makes lots of potions. It was a black and white manga it had beast in it but I don’t remember names. It’s like god made a mistake and transfer world her and gave her a house and she make potions in it.

It was probably within the last 2-3 years that I read it.

When go out her in the new world she asked for a house and the house is in the woods near a village she goes to sell potions in it. She some how attracted mystical beast to her oh and there is a demon that protects her and people don’t like demons cause they think god didn’t make them but god did make them they was worried god had abandon them.

She sells the potions in the town/village close to where she lives.  She’s a young girl who starts with a house and stays there for a while before going to learn about world and sells potions. Oh and she meets and elf guy who lost his way to the town and ends up at her house. And the beast are some mystical beast.

It’s been a few years since I read it and it didn’t have many chapters so I was like I’ll come back when there are more but I don’t remember the name and when I Googled off context clues the only one that popped up was survival with potions.

And I know it’s not that one. I don’t believe it was adult themed either not that guy reincarnated as a girl and is op and has adult fun with herself. It’s not the box garden either I found this manga when I was looking at that one though because it has some similarities.

- It’s not '*[I shall survive using potions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Shall_Survive_Using_Potions!)*'

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  There's really very little information here; can you maybe describe what the character looks like and what kind of potions she makes (and why)?  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: This question is extremely terse. You could improve it by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, was this in black-and-white or colour? What was her name? Did it have adult themes (including nudity)? What did her potions do? Who did she give her potions to? Did she sell them? Was there a love-interest character? What sort of house did she live in? Was the 'other world' fantastical (with magic and monsters)?

Comment: Do you remember what the potions do? Generic HP recovery? MP recovery? Cure illness? Food seasoning? Can you put a year (an estimate is fine) on "a few years since I read it"?

Comment: Did it involve her making magic powered sex toys?

Comment: If so, this might be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262754/manga-where-male-main-character-got-isekaied-and-turned-into-a-witch-girl

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I believe the line "I don’t believe it was adult themed either not that guy reincarnated as a girl and is op and has adult fun with herself" was explicitly ruling that story out.

Comment: Ah, I misread the sentence.

Comment: I'll list some other candidates. They're worse matches than what I posted, so I don't think any of them are it, but could you explicitly rule them out? "Midori no Mahou to Kaori no Tsukaite" - herbs, not potions, but has beasts. "Hazure Potion ga Shouyu datta no de Ryouri suru koto ni shimashita" - she finds the potions, doesn't make them. "Tenisaki wa Kusushi ga Sukunai Sekaideshita" - gods mistake explicitly mentioned, but it looks like she's with nobles, not her own house.

Comment: so it starts god made a mistake she gets sent to another world and she ask god for a house. the divine beast in that world flock to her they do look like regular animals. It’s black and white manga. There are demons that no one likes because that think that they are an abomination but god did create them and did not forget them. There is a demon that watches over her and protects her. The divine beast a sheep a black chicken I think and some regular looking animals that seem weird to them because it is a fantasy world.

Comment: I just remembered it wasn’t potions she made she was a blacksmith I probably confused it because I couldn’t think of what it was but she was a blacksmiths and asked god for a house

Comment: @Keyofall I think I found it. Could you edit the question to mention blacksmithing instead of potions? Otherwise the answer is gonna look weird.

Answer (score 3):

This is not *[The Alchemist of the Miniature Garden: The Daily Life of the Girl Beloved by God](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-alchemist-of-the-miniature-garden-the-daily-life-of-the-girl-beloved-by-god)*. This answer was written before the OP remember that the reincarnated woman was a blacksmith, not a potion seller.

> Hinami Kusunoki **makes an exchange with a god** -- to save her younger sister's life, she'll begin living in an isekai. She can't fight magical beasts, but with the help of the skills that the god gifted her, **she'll make delicious potions -- and lots of them!** Just because Hinami spends her days in this alternate world leisurely doesn't mean that there aren't an abundace of problems to solve...!

This is not a perfect match but there are enough similarities that it's worth considering. The protagonist does not transmigrate due to god's mistake, but rather due to explicitly requesting a favor to cure her sister. She is sent to the middle of a forest in another world and granted potion-making skills and a house. She is tasked with gathering "points" - initially all of her potions are exchanged for these points, but eventually she also sells them in town.

[image: The house in the forest]

There is a beast in it - a "snow rabbit" approaches her and acts friendly, and she more or less adopts it as a pet. It eventually gains a human form and helps out around the house and shop.

[image]

There is an elf, but unless I'm misunderstanding the sequence of events, he never really becomes "lost". He aspires to become an adventurer and meets the protagonist in town; shortly after he's injured by an extremely weak monster and she treats him with a potion.

Comment: Thanks I know that one too alt name box garden but it’s not that one.

Answer (score 1):

This is *[That Time God Killed me by Accident and Brought me Back as a Blacksmith in Another World](https://myanimelist.net/manga/155462)*.

> Melia, a former office worker, was reborn in another world by chance. She was always working in her previous life, so now she wants to live leisurely in her new world. God grants her wish by making her younger and **giving her the blacksmithing skills** she had always longed for. Melia was excited to be able to blacksmith every day and enjoy her new life. But it turns out that in this new world, her blacksmithing skills are pretty special. It seems like her quiet days were not meant to be...

The protagonist is an office worker who dies of overwork and is reincarnated in another world. God appears and explicitly states that her death was a mistake:

[image]

She asks god for blacksmithing skills, as she's a fan of crafting games. He reincarnates her in a game-like world, with blacksmithing skills, an inventory, a house/smithy, makes her younger, and gives her some cash.

Her house is in the middle of nowhere; chapter 1 involves her trying to find a nearby village and getting lost. After meeting some villagers and showing off her skills, she goes to the guild, sells some weapons she made, and gets permission to set up a market stand.

The scene with the demon is in chapter 4. After selling her goods at the market, she has a load of cash and is attacked by thugs. A demon that discovered her house appeared out of nowhere flies in and saves her. He realizes that she has a divine aura, but treats him kindly, which leads to him believing that demons are not, in fact, abandoned by god.

[image] [image]